# Interpreting Nominal Variables

Tags: fitting

```
data = {{a, 0, 1}, {b, 2, 2}, {a, 2, 1.8}, {b, 0, 2.5}};
nom = LinearModelFit[data, {x, y}, {x, y}, NominalVariables -> x]
Normal[nom]
LinearModelFit[data, {x, y}, {x, y}, 
  NominalVariables -> All] // Normal
```

> output = 2.175 +0.07499999999999996(y) - 0.8500000000000001
>   DiscreteIndicator[x,a,{a,b}]

Can someone help me interpret the output from this code? Its from the mathematics documentation guide. Does this mean that the effect of "a" has a 
negative effect of .85 on the total effect?

Answer (score 3):

You might very well get a more complete answer about interpreting "dummy" variables from Cross Validated (http://stats.stackexchange.com) and find existing answers there.  However, here is the short version for your model and data.

Because `x` has two values (`a` and `b`), you are essentially fitting two intercepts.  Call those $a$ and $b$.  (And I'll also use $a$ and $b$ to denote the two different data sources.)  Without giving any other options to `LinearModelFit`, Mathematica gives you $b$ and $a-b$ which are estimated to be 2.175 and -0.8500000000000001, respectively.

So the intercept $a$ is 2.175 + (-0.8500000000000001) = 1.325.

I wouldn't label $a$ as having a negative effect but rather it is simply 0.85 units less than $b$ unless you can justify that $b$ is from a "standard" procedure.  It might very well be that the $a$ intercept comes from the standard procedure and procedure $b$ would then have a positive effect.  But all this assumes that either $a$ or $b$ can be labeled as a comparative standard.  And that is not information that is intrinsic to the numbers.

If you want the separate intercepts, use the following:

```
nom = LinearModelFit[data, {x, y}, {x, y}, NominalVariables -> x, 
  IncludeConstantBasis -> False] // Normal
```

> 0.075 y + 1.325 DiscreteIndicator[x, a, {a, b}] + 
>    2.175 DiscreteIndicator[x, b, {a, b}]

Hopefully your real data consists of many more than 4 data points.

Comment: DiscreteIndicator[x,a,{a,b}]

Comment: I assume you're asking a question.  `DiscreteIndicator[x,a,{a,b}]` is 1 when `x==a` and 0 otherwise.